# Creating Auto form filler with python and selenium webdriver but i'm unable to auto fill textbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, textbox

```
from selenium import webdriver  
import time
br = webdriver.Chrome()
br.get('https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp')  
login_form = br.find_element_by_link_text('CHALLAN NO./ITNS 281').click()  
radio = br.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='radio'][value='0021']") [0].click()  
tan = br.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='text'][name='TAN']")[0].click()  
time.sleep(2)  
tan.send_keys("something")
```

Everything works `except send_keys`

Unable to get the text to be filled in text field and gets the error

```
Attribute error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Answer (score 4):

`click()` doesn't return any value, you can't click on it. Keep the element returned from `find_element` and use it to click and send keys

```
tan = br.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='text'][name='TAN']")[0]
tan.click()
tan.send_keys("something")
```